# React component not re-rendering on setState({})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I've read through a bunch of other posts, and I can't figure out why my files don't load.

I'm using `setState` not `state =` and so on. But anyway, here's the code, if anybody has any ideas, I'd be very happy!

Essentially, the component mounts, then runs `getClientFiles()`, which pulls an array of references. Then this function executes `getFileData()` which takes each of those reference IDs, and pulls back the file information, which gets stored in `this.state.client_files`, and then mapped over in the JSX.

The `currentUser.first_name` populates just fine. But my understanding is that it's running the `getClientFiles()` asynchronously, and therefore doesn't have the `file_refs` on first run. My assumption was, though, by using `setState({ file_refs: file_refs})` is that the component should re-render... but it doesn't.

Note: If I refresh the page, the files load. So it is only on initial login that they don't populate.

I'm fairly new to React... so please be kind! If you notice other issues in the code here, it'd be great if you pointed them out.

```
class Client extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      header: "PartnerPortal",
      client_files: [],
      file_refs: [],
      user_id: ""
    };

  }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getClientFiles();
    };

    getClientFiles() {
      let id = this.props.currentUser.user_id;
      let file_refs = [];

      axios.get(`/users/get-client-files/${id}`)
        .then ( res => {
          console.log(res.data.response);
          let response = res.data.response;

          for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            file_refs.push(response[i].file_id);
          };
          this.setState({
            file_refs: file_refs
          })
          this.getFileData();
        })
    }


    getFileData() {

      let fileRefs = this.state.file_refs;
      let fileData = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < fileRefs.length; i++) {
        axios.get("/files/get-file/" + fileRefs[i])
          .then( res => {
            fileData.push(res.data.response);
            this.setState({
              client_files: fileData,
              data_returned: true
            })
          })
          .catch( err => console.log(err.response.data))
      }
    }

  render() {

      return(
      <Fragment>
         <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h4>
                  <em>Welcome, {this.props.currentUser.first_name} {this.props.currentUser.last_name}</em>
                </h4>
                <h5>
                  <em>{ this.props.currentUser.client_name}</em>
                </h5>

                <div className="fileBox">

                  {this.state.client_files.map(( file, i ) => (
                    <a key={i} style={styles.linkCard} href={file.file_url} target="_blank">
                    <div key={i} className="clientCard">

                      { file.file_type === "PDF" &&
                        <span><i className="fas fa-file-pdf pdf"></i></span>
                      }
                      { file.file_type === "DOC" &&
                        <span><i className="fas fa-file-alt doc"></i></span>
                      }
                      { file.file_type === "Directory" &&
                        <span><i className="fas fa-folder-open dir"></i></span>
                      }
                      { file.file_type === "Presentation" &&
                        <span><i className="fas fa-file-powerpoint ppt"></i></span>
                      }
                      <p>{file.file_name}</p>

                    </div>
                    </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Update:
I have updated the code to the follow based on suggestions in the answers.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.getClientFiles();
    };

    getClientFiles() {
      let id = this.props.currentUser.user_id;
      let file_refs = [];

      axios.get(`/users/get-client-files/${id}`)
        .then ( res => {
          console.log(res.data.response);
          let response = res.data.response;

          for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            file_refs.push(response[i].file_id);
            this.setState({
              file_refs
            }, () => {
            this.getFileData();
          })
        }
      });
    }
```

Unfortunately, still not getting the files until after a page refresh :(

Comment: Grab the react dev tools for chrome and monitor the state for file_refs. Or stick a console.log("+++", file_refs); as the first line inside render and see if the results are what you expect. Also, on your setState, call getFileData as the 2nd parameter as it depends on state.file_refs being populated.

Comment: Using react dev tools, I can see that the client_files array does not populate on first render. Refreshing the page, though, does populate the array.

Comment: Are you sure you want to setState each time inside the loop or do you want to setState once after `fileData.push(res.data.response);` runs inside the loop?

Comment: setting state outside of the forloop doesn't work because `fileData` isn't accessible (a `console.log` shows an empty `[]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

Setting state with `returned_data: false`, and then triggering the `getClientFiles()` function prior to returning the app. The function then sets state `returned_data: true`.

```
render() {

      if (this.state.returned_data === false) {
        this.getClientFiles();
      }

      return( <App /> );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely on these lines:

```
this.setState({
    file_refs: file_refs
})
this.getFileData();
```

`setState` is asynchronous, so you will not have guaranteed access to `this.state` immediately after invoking that method. You need to move the call to `getFileData` into the second parameter of `setState`, that will ensure that it will be invoked after state is actually set (i.e. you can use `this.state`):

```
getClientFiles() {
    let id = this.props.currentUser.user_id;
    let file_refs = [];

    axios.get(`/users/get-client-files/${id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.response);
            let response = res.data.response;

            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                file_refs.push(response[i].file_id);
            }
            this.setState({
                file_refs
            }, () => {
                this.getFileData();
            });
        });
}
```

See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Updated the code as far as I understood your comment... but still no dice. Did I misunderstand something? Edited the original post.

Comment: I'm not sure why you moved the `setState` into the for loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too. Still doesn't render the files on first load.

Comment: The issue seems to be the `this.props.currentUser.user_id` ... when `getClientFiles()` runs, the id is undefined.